# Get the name of object model loaded via OBJLoader on hover - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to access the name of object model, defined during loading, from the array returned from intersectObjects function? The below code is logging undefined for some reason.

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  objLoader.setPath('obj/');
  objLoader.load('deadpool.obj', function(object){
    objModel = object;
    objModel.name = 'ObjectModel3D';
    modelHasLoaded = true;
    scene.add(objModel);
});

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(eventTarget){
  var intersects = checkIntersection(eventTarget);
  if(intersects.length){
    console.log(intersects[0].name);
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. You have to set the name using **objModel.userData.name** attribute. To access it on hover, use **intersects[0].object.parent.name**. Hope this helps future queries.

Comment: Yes ! thank you ! 3 hours blocked on this. Could access to the URL attribute in the userData object using `video.src = intersects[0].object.parent.userData.URL;`